# Create menu using Map but to remove the { } and ", "

Tags: java, menu, hashmap, java-17

I have this menu created :

```
@SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfCollection")
HashMap<Integer, String> menu = new HashMap<>();

menu.put(1, "Show clients from banks" + "\n");
menu.put(2, "Create new bank" + "\n");
menu.put(3, """
        \t. "Choose a bank from where you want to see the clients:
             A. BNP
             B. ING
             C. KBC
        \s""");
System.out.println(menu);
```

and I get the output bit as  you can see in the output down , there are some { } and ", "  that I do not want them, is there other way  by using HashMap to create  something similar ?

OUTPUT:

```
{1=Show clients from banks
, 2=Create new bank
, 3=    . "Choose a bank from where you want to see the clients: 
     A. BNP
     B. ING
     C. KBC
 }
```

Desired OUTPUT - as it will  be is i  will use  `sout` , but i must use   this instead `HashMap<Integer, String> menu = new HashMap<>();`:

```
 1=Show clients from banks
 2=Create new bank
 3= . "Choose a bank from where you want to see the clients: 
     A. BNP
     B. ING
     C. KBC
```

Comment: Just don't use HashMap's `toString()`; iterate through the map and format the data any way you want.

Comment: Thanks  for hint ,   i used this 
`menu.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " - " + value));`  that  works jsut fine for me :)

Comment: A `HashMap` does not guaranty to retain the order. You need a `LinkedHashMap` to ensure that the iteration order will always match the insertion order. But why are you using a map at all? What’s the supposed advantage over just using a single text block containing the entire output?

Comment: @Holger , that it was what i  should use  for the "project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to override the toString() for HashMap, that's a bad way to do it.  Create your own printMenu() method to iterate yourself.  I'd also remove the new lines from your options.

```
public void printMenu(Map<Integer, String> menu) {
    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : menu) {
       System.out.println(String.format("%d) %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support m  but i  will go  with  `menu.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " - " + value));`  +1 Accepted

Comment: I like streams for some things, but for readability, I think a good old for loop is enough.

Comment: that sounds fear  , i do  like them ffor that too  but in most situation to make it optimal and to have less lines  streams are first place for me . :),  Thanks again  xD

Comment: Speaking of readability, you know that `System.out.println(String.format("%d) %s", …))` is the same as `System.out.printf("%d) %s%n", …)`?